# How to implement a custom Swift object with constraints?

Tags: ios, swift

**Summary:**

I want to implement my own UIView object with specific layout constraints utilizing Swift 3. I'm not sure how to configure the layout constraints in the object I'm customizing. I was thinking of passing in a reference to the super view to append the layout constraints onto.

**Question:**

How can I implement my own custom user interface object while also maintaining that objects layout constraints in the model instead of the view?

**Code:**
**Custom View:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class CustomView: UIView {
    var header: UIView?
    var users: [Array<OtherObject>]?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
        //for debug validation
        print("My Custom Init");
        return;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented");
    }

    func configureTitleHeader(){
        header = UIView()
    }

    func configureConstraints(superView: UIView){
        self.configureTitleHeader()
        let titleConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.header!, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.header!, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.header!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.header!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        ]
        superView.addConstraints(titleConstraints)
    }
}
```

**UINavigationController:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let customView = CustomView()
        customView.configureConstraints(superView: self.view)
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
}
```

Comment: You can't add constraints that refer to the superview until your view is already in the hierarchy. Once you've done that, the view always has a reference to its superview: [`var superview: UIView? { get }`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622474-superview). Aside from that, what you're doing is technically fine, although it's a bit strange for a subview to know so much about its context that it can place itself like this: it diminishes re-usability. It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Unless the frame of my CusomView was always `UIScreen.main.bounds`...I wouldn't do it this way.  I would instead just include frame as an instantiation parameter of the customView ie do `let customView = CustomView(frame:someFrame)` then easily call `configureConstraints` from the init method of my CustomView. This way you're implicitly passing the SuperView

Comment: Your height of 10 seems like something that should be part of the `intrinsicContentSize`, not a layout constraint.